# Stemming - code examples or open source projects?

Tags: algorithm, tags, nlp, stemming

Stemming is something that's needed in tagging systems.  I use delicious, and I don't have time to manage and prune my tags.  I'm a bit more careful with my blog, but it isn't perfect.  I write software for embedded systems that would be much more functional (helpful to the user) if they included stemming.

For instance:
Parse
Parser
Parsing

Should all mean the same thing to whatever system I'm putting them into.

Ideally there's a BSD licensed stemmer somewhere, but if not, where do I look to learn the common algorithms and techniques for this?

Aside from BSD stemmers, what other open source licensed stemmers are out there?

-Adam

Comment: Someone needs to add http://snowball.tartarus.org/ as an answer  (hint, hint) ...

Comment: But I'd like to see others, and specifically more information about the algorithms used.

Comment: FYI: Snowball has a package of their algorithms available for download.

Comment: @Adam: I was getting there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) stemmer (C & Java)
I've used it's Python binding, [PyStemmer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer)

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [nltk toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/Home) written in python. It has a very functional [stemmer](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/stem.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another option for stemming would be WordNet, along with [one of its APIs](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/links#local). Some [basic information on stemming and lemmatization](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html), including a description of the Porter stemming algorithm, can be found online in [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-csli.stanford.edu/~hinrich/information-retrieval-book.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) has a stemmer in, I believe (and IIRC it lets you use your own one if you want).

EDIT: Just checked, and Lucence refers to the [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) site which is an open source stemming library as far as I can tell.