# Converting words between verb/noun/adjective forms with java

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I would like to convert words between verb/noun/adjective forms using **java** and **StanfordNLP**.
Is there a way to do this ? As far as i know ntlk supply functions as below;

```
print nounize('written') # => ['writer']
print adjectivate('write') # => ['written']
```

I prefer StanfordNLP methods but there may be other solutions or suggestions ?

Appreciate any clue or help

Best Regards

Comment: hi! have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the past tense of a verb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520501/how-do-you-get-the-past-tense-of-a-verb)