# How to detect string suffixes and remove these suffixed elements from list? - Python

Tags: python, string, list

How to detect string suffixes and remove these suffixed elements from list?
**I understand that this looks like an NLP, stemming/lemmatization task but the task requires a simpler function.**

Given, i need to remove elements that has `s` and `es` suffixes if the non-suffixed items exist in the list:

```
alist = ['bar','barbar','foo','foos','barbares','foofoos','bares']
```

I need to output:

```
alist = ['bar','barbar','foo','foofoos']
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work because when i sort out the alist, it gets `['bar', 'barbar', 'barbares', 'bares', 'foo', 'foofoos', 'foos']` not `['bar', 'bares', 'barbar', 'barbares',  'foo', 'foos', 'foofoos']`

```
alist = ['bar','barbar','foo','foos','barbares','foofoos','bares']

prev = ""
no_s_list = []
for i in sorted(alist):
  if i[-2:] == "es" and i[:-2] == prev:
    continue
  elif i[-1:] == "s" and i[:-1] == prev:
    contine
  else:
    prev = i
    no_s_list.append(i)
```

The above outputs:

```
>>> sorted(alist)
['bar', 'barbar', 'barbares', 'bares', 'foo', 'foofoos', 'foos']
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization

Comment: it's not a stemming/lemmatization task!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def rm_suffix(s,suffixes):
    for suf in suffixes:
       if s.endswith(suf):
          return s[:-len(suf)]
    return s

alist = ['bar','barbar','foo','foos','barbares','foofoos','bares']
salist = set(alist)
suffixes = ('es','s')
blist = [x for x in alist 
         if (not x.endswith(suffixes)) or (rm_suffix(x,suffixes) not in salist)]
print blist  # ['bar', 'barbar', 'foo', 'foofoos']
```

Comment: Thanks a million. should have thought of `str.endswith` =)

Comment: I was going to suggest to use a different sorting function, but this solution is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `regex` here:

`re.split()` will return something like:

`barbar` --> `['barbar']`

`foos` --> `['foo', 's', '']`

`barbares` --> `['barbar', 'es', '']`

`foofoos` --> `['foofoo', 's', '']`

So, if the length of returned list is greater than 1 and first element in this returned list is found in `alist` then you can remove it.

`code`:

```
In [106]: alist = ['bar','barbar','foo','foos','barbares','foofoos','bares']

In [107]: s=set(alist)

In [108]: for x in s.copy():
     sol=re.split(r'(es|s)$',x)
     if len(sol)>1 and sol[0] in s:
         s.remove(x)
   .....:         

In [109]: s
Out[109]: set(['bar', 'foofoos', 'barbar', 'foo'])
```