# Wordnet Morphmaps: Why does WordNet 3.0 have limited number of morphmaps

Tags: wordnet

I have been analysing the WordNet 3.0 MySql database files, that I downloaded from:
http://www.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/

And have notices that there are only 4962 morphmaps present.  This means, that if I search for the term "Carrying" I get zero results.

If I search for "Carrying" however, on the WordNet 3.1 search page: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

I get directed to "Carry" - which is an expected result.

I assume that Wordnet 3.1 has more rows in its morphmaps table, and that is why "Carrying" yields the correct result.

Does anyone know:
1) Does WordNet 3.1 have more morphmaps than 3.0?
2) Where I might source the 3.1 mysql database files for Wordnet 3.1
3) Are there other ways of getting more morphmaps into Wordnet?

Thanks for your kind assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use morphmaps to convert a word into its base form. You use **lemmatizer**.

You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization) to see many lemmatizers available.

The Web version of WordNet already incorporates some software, it's not just plain search on the database. And even so, after lemmatization it's searching on the sense database (say, index.sense), not morphmaps database.

Comment: Thanks Justhalf, I managed to come to this conclusion as well, and successfully implemented phpmorphy, but I am open to trying others