# Why cowardly becomes cowardli after stemming?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stemming

I noticed that after applying Porter stemming (from NLTK library) I get strange stems such as *"cowardli"* or *"contrari"*. For me they don't look like stems at all.

Is it okay? Could it be that I made a mistake smwhere?

Here is my code:

```
string = string.lower()
tokenized = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(string,"[a-z]+")
filtered = [w for w in tokenized if w not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")]


stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
stemmed = []
for w in filtered:
    stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(w))
```

And here is the text I used for processing http://pastebin.com/XUMNCYAU (beginning of "crime and punishment" book by Dostoevsky).

Comment: If the result doesn't look correct to you, then you're probably looking for lemmas, not stems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization?rq=1

Comment: No, I'm specifically looking for stems. But I now see that Porter Stemmer translates some of the example words in a way similar to how it transformed mine. Probably I didn't understand the concept of stemming well enough, I'll dig deeper

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's look at the different stemmers/lemmatizer that `NLTK` has:

```
>>> from nltk import stem
>>> lancaster = stem.lancaster.LancasterStemmer()
>>> porter = stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
>>> snowball = stem.snowball.EnglishStemmer()
>>> wnl = stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> word = "cowardly"
>>> lancaster.stem(word)
'coward'
>>> porter.stem(word)
u'cowardli'
>>> snowball.stem(word)
u'coward'
>>> wnl.stem(word)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WordNetLemmatizer' object has no attribute 'stem'
>>> wnl.lemmatize(word)
'cowardly'
```

Note: WordNetLemmatizer is not a stemmer, thus it outputs the lemmatize of `cowardly` and in this case it is the same word.

Seems like Porter stemmer is the only one that changes `cowardly -> cowardli`, let's look at the code to see why it happens, see http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/porter.html#PorterStemmer.

It seems like this is the part that is the `ly -> li`:

```
def _step1c(self, word):
    """step1c() turns terminal y to i when there is another vowel in the stem.
    --NEW--: This has been modified from the original Porter algorithm so that y->i
    is only done when y is preceded by a consonant, but not if the stem
    is only a single consonant, i.e.

       (*c and not c) Y -> I

    So 'happy' -> 'happi', but
      'enjoy' -> 'enjoy'  etc

    This is a much better rule. Formerly 'enjoy'->'enjoi' and 'enjoyment'->
    'enjoy'. Step 1c is perhaps done too soon; but with this modification that
    no longer really matters.

    Also, the removal of the vowelinstem(z) condition means that 'spy', 'fly',
    'try' ... stem to 'spi', 'fli', 'tri' and conflate with 'spied', 'tried',
    'flies' ...
    """
    if word[-1] == 'y' and len(word) > 2 and self._cons(word, len(word) - 2):
        return word[:-1] + 'i'
    else:
        return word
```

Comment: So if we try to get meaning using Senti Wordnet or Wordnet will it return appropriate meaning?