# Stanford CorpNLP returning wrong results

Tags: java-7, stanford-nlp, eclipse-3.4, lemmatization

I am trying lemmatization with stanford corenlp following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771918/how-do-i-do-word-stemming-or-lemmatization) question. My environment is:-

- Java 1.7
- Eclipse 3.4.0
- StandfordCoreNLP version 3.4.1 ([downloaded from here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)).

my code snippet is:-

```
//...........lemmatization starts........................

    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma"); 
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props, false);
    String text = "painting"; 
    Annotation document = pipeline.process(text);  

    List<edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    for(edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap sentence: sentences) 

    {    
        for(CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
        {       
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);      
            String lemma = token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class); 
            System.out.println("lemmatized version :" + lemma);
        }
    }

    //...........lemmatization ends.........................
```

the output i get is:-

```
lemmatized version :painting
```

where i expect

```
lemmatized version :paint
```

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this example is that the word painting can be the present participle of *to paint* or a noun and the output of the lemmatizer depends on the part-of-speech tag assigned to the original word.

If you run the tagger only on the fragment *painting*, then there is no context that could help the tagger (or a human) to decide how the word should be tagged. In this case it picked the tag `NN` and the lemma of the noun *painting* is in fact *painting*.

If you run the same code with the sentence "I am painting a flower." the tagger should correctly tag *painting* as `VBG` and the lemmatizer should return *paint*.

Comment: thats ok. but what if i have words like "painting" and i need "paint" out of it. what other api / tool i should be using? i cannot send a sentence to API.

Comment: There won't be any tool that will be able to infer the right POS tag based on a single word if the tag depends on the context. However, if you know in advance that the word will be a verb, you could manually tag it and then run the lemmatizer.

Comment: Sebastian. pl help me with manual tagging of words. i could not find any code on net

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724111/manual-tagging-of-words-using-stanford-cornlp/28785523#28785523